# Edit the font size and graph thickness in plot( bootstrap_p)

Tags: r, plot

I need to edit the font size of bootstrap plot, but seems that all the options work with plot to edit the graph, do not work for plotting the bootstrap. I use the below code, but nothing changed when I changed the number. I also need to have a main caption above the graph.

[image: bootstrap plot]

```
bs_pl <- bootstrap_p(m_pl, no_of_sims=1000, threads=8, seed = 123)
plot(bs_pl,cex.main = 3,bty="n",cex.axis = 1.3)
```

Comment: From which package is `bootstrap_p`? What object does it return (you should be able to find it out in the section "Value" of the help page of the function)? Lett us assume that the retrun value is of class `foo`: then `plot` (it is a generic function) will call `plot.foo`. What options does this function list and does it recognize parameters set with `par`?

Comment: from poweRlaw package.  Data is time series data from one variable.the whole code is as below: m_pl <- conpl$new(data)
est_pl <- estimate_xmin(m_pl)
est_pl$xmin #k_min
est_pl$pars #gamma
est_pl$gof #D
#Investigate goodness of fit
bs_pl <- bootstrap_p(m_pl, no_of_sims=1000, threads=8, seed = 123)
plot(bs_pl)

Comment: The sample code does not help, because you (yourself!) must figure out what function `plot` actually calls (remember: `plot` is a generic function and thus calls a method of the object which is passed to it). This in turn requires figuring out the class of the object returned by `bootstrap_p`, which *you* must find out, e.g. by reading the documentation of `bootstrap_p`.